# Set up Application Insights for Older WCF Library

Tags: wcf, azure-application-insights

I've "setup" AI through the context menu in VS 2017 when selecting the "Configure Application Insights" option. It doesn't set up like ASP.NET sites.  it didn't add AI dll's and there isn't a ApplicationInsights.config
But it does state I've connected to the AI i created in Azure. yet i don't see the instrumentation Key anywhere. Also When I rum the WCF service noting gets logged. is there a specific way we need to set up AI for this? I couldn't find articles on how to do this. The only files that were generated was in the Connected Services AI folder and ConnectedService.json

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, of TFS for some reason it didn't allow checkout of project file so it created the files but couldn't add it to the project. I checkout the project manually and delete the files. Then added AI and it worked as expected.